# Build 32 bit Apache httpd RPM

Tags: apache, 32bit-64bit, httpd.conf, rpmbuild

I'm trying to build Apache httpd RPM from the source tarball as mentioned in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html

I need to generate 32 bit RPM

However, I could not find any documentation on how to build 32 bit version from the source. Essentially, what options need to be provided to "configure" to build 32 bit httpd server.